# How do you handle scope of variables in Angular components (not controllers)?

Tags: angular, typescript, scope

I want to check for admin access for the logged in user and show a toggle button if they are that shows their current status like so:

```js
<button id="admin_button" (click)="admin=(admin?0:1)">{{ admin?'Admin':'Not Admin'}}</button>
```

This is in my app.component file because I want it just below the top banner navigation for all pages. Then, in my home component I want to react to the admin status like so:

```js
<p *ngIf="admin" class="controls">Edit</p>
```

The idea is that the edit button is available to admins only, but the toggle button lets me switch the page easily between admin and non-admin view. The problem is that the home component doesn't know about the admin variable and I don't know how to fix that.

All the tutorials and guides and SO questions I see are talking about $scope and $rootScope that apply only to controllers. There will surely be a series of "application scope vars" (basically globals or session vars) that I will need, but how do I make that happen?

Comment: What version of Angular are you working with? `angular-js`?

Comment: Angular version 8+

Comment: you can have that a variable in a service with rootScope and then use it from there wherever you need

Comment: TypeError: _co.$rootScope is undefined.

Comment: I tried adding an admin var to the api.service file that all pages import, but that didn't make the rootscope error change when I used *ngIf="$rootScope.admin"

Comment: Why don't just pass down it like `<home [admin]="admin" />`?

Comment: Pass what down? Where would that code be? What is this syntax? Where is this kind of thing documented?